# ruby file download with webkit driver

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

Is is possible to download a file using webkit driver? The operation only works when using selenium.
The download is triggered by clicking a link which in return sends a get request to retrieve the file and download.
I prefer not using the get request.

Answer (score 1):

capybara-webkit doesn't support file download, although you can probably access the content of the file in `page.body` after clicking the link.  If the URL for the download is accessible on the page you can grab that and any necessary cookies from capybara-webkit and use something like curl to initiate a download of the file.